# What are the difference between reactJS props and refs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting confused with `props` and `refs` in ReactJS. Can anybody explain me the difference between them with proper example.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Props are used to pass parameters which should be static (on the contrary of state). For example you can pass a size or name from an upperView to a lowerView (nested views);

Interesting part on props: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html

refs are used to acces the real DOM and not the virtual DOM of react. It's needed when you need to access the real DOM.

This part is interesting :https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html

```
 this.setState({userInput: ''}, function() {
        // This code executes after the component is re-rendered
        React.findDOMNode(this.refs.theInput).focus();   // Boom! Focused!
      });
```

The example above show you how to access a DOM element **properly** when the state is updated.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

For sure there are differences between, one mostly use for selecting the DOM, one for getting data as a property, I create the image below and explain few major differences:

[image]

Also this the sample of grandparent, parent and child components which using `ref` and `props` to pass data, it's a good example to understand when and how they get used, please pay attention how ref helping to get in deeper component by referencing to the element:

```
function Child(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <input ref={props.inputRef} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Parent(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      My input: <Child inputRef={props.inputRef} />
    </div>
  );
}

class Grandparent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Parent
        inputRef={el => this.inputElement = el}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are two different things.

Props: Use them to pass any parameters to your component.

Refs: Shortcut for references. These are references to your DOM elements. Use them if you need to access raw DOM element for some reason. For example to add custom event handler via .addEventListener() function.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to the answer above by François Richard, u might wanna read:
https://github.com/uberVU/react-guide/blob/master/props-vs-state.md

because the confusion is more often between state and props.
good luck